# Is this part of the engine intake an aerodynamic component?

Tags: jet-engine, turboprop, inlet, turboshaft

Just was seeing this image:

[image]

And found out there is a component that split up the intake into two parts. Is this part of the engine intake an aerodynamic component? if so, how does it work?

**Edit:** I think the plane is a [General Atomics MQ-9 Reaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper).